# Автоустановка расширения для google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Как установить расширение в браузер хром программным путем.
Запуск файла на компе → расширение добавлено в хром

Как это реализовать, какой файл в хроме отвечает за управление установленными расширениями?

Кое как разобрался с документацией, создал файл  `nojpnepbplnoojhiinbpegidccgolald.json` (в качестве имени использовал `id` приложения, его получил установив плагин к себе в хром и скопировав его `id`) в папке

```
C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\31.0.1650.63\Extensions
```

со следующим содержанием:

```
{
"external_crx": "C:\Sdsattings.crx",

"external_version": "1.0"
}
```

`crx` файл разместил на диске C, перезапускаю хром и ничего не происходит

Comment: Установка через рестор тоже ничего не дала

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Приветствую.

В целях безопасности в Chrome на Mac / Windows можно устанавливать расширения только с Chrome Web Store. Т.е. по факту в Chrome добавляется информация о том какое расширение надо обновить и после запуска браузера он подгружает расширение.

---

1. **Windows**

   1.1. В Windows установка происходит через реестр в раздел:

   - 32-bit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions`
   - 64-bit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions`

   1.2. Создать новый ключ (папка) вида `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc` (*ID расширения в Chrome Web Store*)

   1.3. Внутри этого ключа создать свойство `update_url` со значением `https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx` (*ссылка на Chrome Web Store*)
2. **Mac**

   2.1. Создать файл типа `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc.json` (*ID расширения в Chrome Web Store*)

   2.2.  Содержимое файла должно быть таким

   ```
   {
     "external_update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
   }
   ```

   2.3. Положить его в папку:

   - для определенного пользователя `~USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/`
   - для всех `/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/External Extensions/`
3. **Вариант для Linux**

   Для Linux можно устанавливать как с удаленного источника, так и с локального `.crx` файла

   3.1. Создать файл типа `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbcccccccccc.json` (ID расширения)

   3.2. Содержимое файла должно быть таким

   - при установке с локального файла

     ```
     {
       "external_crx": "/path/to/extension.crx",
       "external_version": "1.0"
     }
     ```
   - при установке по ссылке (пример)

     ```
     {
       "external_update_url": "http://myhost.com/mytestextension/updates.xml"
     }
     ```

   3.3. Положить файл в любую из папок (должен иметь права на чтение всеми):

   `/opt/google/chrome/extensions/`

   `/usr/share/google-chrome/extensions/`

---

Также возможно установить расширение простым открытием `.crx` файла из Chrome, если браузер запустить с флагом `–enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не поискать ответ на официальном сайте?

Developer's Guide -> Finishing -> Other Deployment Options
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html

Comment: Кое как разобрался, создал файл nojpnepbplnoojhiinbpegidccgolald.json в папке Chrome\Application\31.0.1650.63\Extensions со следующим содержанием: 
{
    "external_crx": "C:\Sdsattings.crx",
    "external_version": "1.0"
}

crx файл разместил на диске C, перезапускаю хром и ничего не происходит

Comment: Если что, тут открылся конкурс за более полный ответ на этот же самый вопрос.